# C segmentation fault after accessing the system time by inline assembly

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, inline-assembly

I have been trying to access the system time using inline assembly in C under Ubuntu 16.04. My code looks as follow:

```
struct timeval *date_time;

asm(
    "movl $116, %%eax;"
    "push $0;"
    "push %0;"
    "push $0;"
    "int $0x80;"
    :
    :"b"(date_time)
);
```

Assume I have a couple of lines above stored in specific function. Whenever I call the function it triggers the error code:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

As I am new to inline assembly, there might be something wrong with the code, I guess. Therefore I would be very glad if you could point out what I am doing wrong. Thank you for all of your suggestions.

Comment: I'm not sure where to start.  Where did you get 116?  Isn't the correct value for [sys_time](http://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/) 0xd?  Also, you don't `push` parameters that are being passed to int 80, you store specific values into specific registers.  For example, for sys_time, ebx should contain a pointer to a time_t struct.  Also, when writing inline asm, you must inform the compiler if you are changing the values of any registers.  Since this code changes eax (it's the return value), you must account for that.  BTW, learning asm via inline like this is the hardest possible way.

Comment: `"push %0;"` should probably read `"push $0;"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a *lot* of bugs here, of which the most important are:

- You pushed things onto the stack, but you didn't pop them off again before leaving the inline assembly block.  The compiler doesn't know you did that, so it will look for everything on the stack (such as the return address) in the wrong place afterward.  This is is very likely to be what caused the crash.
- More generally, compilers that use this style of inline assembly don't interpret the assembly instructions *at all*.  They trust you to have used the input, output, clobber annotations correctly.  If you neglect to mention even *one* register or memory area that has been modified, the compiler will generate incorrect code surrounding the assembly insert and the program won't work.
- "Ubuntu 16.04" is a distribution of Linux, so you are using the wrong calling convention.  Linux takes system call arguments in registers, not on the stack, [as documented here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Interfacing_with_Linux), and `gettimeofday` is not system call number 116 on x86-32/Linux.  (Always use the `SYS_foo` constants, from `sys/syscall.h`, for system call numbers.)

Also, it is best to do *as little as possible* in the actual inserted assembly.  In this case, that means just the `int` instruction itself.  Set up arguments using the input and output constraints, instead.  This gives the compiler maximum leeway to optimize.  (If you are writing assembly by hand because the compiler is failing to do a sufficiently good job of optimizing, you should write an entire ".s" file of pure assembly, rather than a .c file with gigantic assembly inserts; this is more maintainable.)

Correct code for this task would be something like

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

struct timeval
call_gettimeofday()
{
    struct timeval ret;
    int dummy;
    asm("int $0x80"
        : "=m" (ret), "=a" (dummy)
        : "1" (SYS_gettimeofday), "b" (&ret), "c" (0));
    assert(!dummy); // gettimeofday should never fail
    return ret;
}
```

As a final note, it is almost always a mistake to use inline assembly to make system calls.  The C library's wrapper functions may be doing more work than is apparent to you, and they know how to use a more efficient trap sequence (using `sysenter` or `syscall` instead of `int`) when possible.  In the case of `gettimeofday`, the difference is even more profound: the C library knows how to do a `gettimeofday` operation *without trapping into the kernel at all!*  (Read up on the [`vDSO`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html) to understand how this is possible.)

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer - this is what I was looking for. You earned my acceptance.